# Adding folder name as paramter to Rsync command in shell script is adding \#015

Tags: shell, rsync

How can I build the `rysnc` command dynamically in shell script? When I use the script below, the folder name is coming incorrectly. ie: \#015 is adding to the end of the folder name like /var/www/data/DataFolder\#015. So, `rsync` is not running saying that folder does not exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
Folder='DataFolder'
rsync -avrz /var/www/data/$Folder -e "ssh -i /var/www/key/rsync-key.out"   myuser@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/data/backup/$Folder
```

But if I replace the variable with exact value, like this:

```
    rsync -avrz /var/www/data/DataFolder-e "ssh -i /var/www/key/rsync-key.out" 
    myuser@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/data/backup/DataFolder
```

it works perfectly.

I'm new to shell scripting.

Comment: `\015` is a carriage return... remove that from your script (or output), and it'll work.

Comment: i didnt use the carriage return in my script. im sorry if im too childish , can you please go through the above script and say me what should i do for fixing it

Comment: Thanks Wrikken. i solved it by the clue you gave. i changed Folder='DataFolder' to Folder='DataFolder'; and it is working fine now. thanks for your kind help

Comment: Well, the `;` shouldn't be needed... But I assume editing it will have removed the (hidden) character ;)